# Problems with special chars encoding with an access mdb database using php

Tags: php, ms-access, encoding, utf-8

My boss is forcing me to use an access mdb database (yes, I'm serious) in a php server.
I can connect it and retrieve data from it, but as you could imagine, I have problems with encodings because I want to work using utf8.

The thing is that now I have two "solutions" to translate Windows-1252 to UTF-8

This is the first way:

`mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252")`.

It works, but the problem is that special chars are not properly converted, for example char º is converted to `\u00ba` and char Ó is converted to \u00d3.

My second way is doing this:

```
mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252"), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8")
```

It works too, but it happens the same, special chars are not correctly converted. Char º is converted to `&ordm;`

Does anybody know how to properly change encoding including special chars?
Or does anybody know how to convert from `&ordm;` and `\u00ba` to something readable?

Comment: Check out the related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28341697/2144390). However, bear in mind that there will always be *some* compatibility issues using PHP+Access+Unicode (e.g., arbitrary Unicode parameter values in SQL queries won't work), so your boss may want to re-think his/her edict re: using that combination of technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
I had the solution from the beginning but I was doing my tests wrong.

My bad.

The right way to do it for me is `mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252")`

But i was checking the result like this:

```
$stringUTF8 = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
echo json_encode($stringUTF8);
```

that's why it was returning unicode chars like `\u20ac`, if I would have done:

```
$stringUTF8 = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
echo $stringUTF8;
```

I should have seen the solution from the beginning but I was wrong. It was `json_encode()` what was turning special chars into unicode chars.

Thanks everybody for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I did simple test to convert codepoint to letters

```
<?php
function codepoint_decode($str) {
    return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
}

$string_with_codepoint = "Ahed \u00d3\u00ba\u00d3";
// $string_with_codepoint = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
$output = codepoint_decode($string_with_codepoint);
echo $output; // Ahed ÓºÓ
```

Credit go for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24763655/2570425)