# Import Access data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

How to load .mdb file into mysql database using php code.

I have a  .mdb file and location is /example/employee.mdb. I need to read record from attendance table and insert it into mysql's emp_attendance table.

What will be PHP logic for that?

Comment: see this : http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php to convert and import the mdb files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Below logic worked for me.

```
$fileNm = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\attendanceData.mdb";
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("ADODB Connection Faild!");
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$fileNm");
    if($conn){
        $data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM em_attendance");
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Like most relational databases, PHP can connect to MS Access and MySQL with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Consider doing so with a dual connection with MySQL. No external, third-party software is required. Below example uses a mock table and fields. Adjust as needed:

Requirements include (no MSAccess.exe installation required):

1. [php_pdo.dll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) extension enabled in .ini file
2. MS Access ODBC Driver *(usually already pre-installed)*
3. Any Windows PC *(pre-built with Jet/ACE SQL engine -Access' underlying engine)*

**PHP Dual PDO Connection**

```
$accdatabase="C:\Path\To\database.accdb";

$host="localhost";
$mydatabase="****";
$username="****";
$password="****";

try { 
  # OPEN BOTH DATABASE CONNECTIONS
  $accConn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBq=$accdatabase;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"); 

  $myConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$mydatabase",$username,$password); 
  $myConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_attendance"; 
  $accstmt = $accConn->query($sql);
  $accstmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

  // FETCH ROWS FROM MS ACCESS
  while($row = $accstmt->fetch()) { 
    // APPEND TO MYSQL
    $mystmt = $myConn->prepare("INSERT INTO emp_attendance (empid, `date`, status, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    # BIND PARAMETERS 
    $mystmt->bindParam(1, $row['empid'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50); 
    $mystmt->bindParam(2, $row['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);    
    $mystmt->bindParam(3, $row['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50); 
    $mystmt->bindParam(4, $row['notes'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);

    # EXECUTE QUERY
    $mystmt->execute();
  }
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {         
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n"; 
    exit; 
}

// CLOSE CONNECTIONS
$accConn = null;
$myConn = null;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried above one, it working with above logic, but finally i have used COM.

Comment: Below is the logic i have used which is also working fine:  $conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("ADODB Connection Faild!");
     $conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$fileNm");
     if($conn){
     $data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM em_attendance");

Comment: Indeed, same connection driver (remove *accdb* option) but different API -PHP's PDO vs Windows' ADO. Just thought using PHP's object library may provide seamless setup especially with MySQL connection in script. But to each his/her own. Happy coding!

Comment: ( cc: @Madhura ) - In my experience, neither `PDO` nor PHP's (deprecated) `odbc_` functions are able to use Access ODBC to retrieve Unicode characters that do not also exist in the Windows-1252 character set. Using `COM` with ADO has been the only way I could find to properly retrieve those characters. (Details in the related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28341697/2144390).)

Comment: Very interesting @GordThompson! Thank you for your comment. We should send a note to the PHP team on this PDO item. I wonder if the newly release PHP 7 resolved this unicode issue.

Answer (score 0):

read the data from mdb to csv

read from csv and insert into mysql

Or

Try this

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10365863-Convert-mdb-to-mysql

Comment: Thank You so much JaNaM.

Answer (score 0):

> MDB is a database file used by Microsoft Access. MDB is Access’s own
>   format which is based on the Access Jet Database Engine. You can open
>   it by Microsoft Access as it is it's own format, also can open it by
>   Microsoft Excel, If you don't have Microsoft Office you don't need to
>   worry about.   MDB files can also be opened by OpenOffice.org, SAS
>   Institute SAS, Wolfram Mathematica, Softpedia MDB Converter¸ and
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. MDB file files can be converted to .TXT
>   or .CSV formats using a MDB Converter. Even if you don't have above
>   all you can download the a free popular tool MDB Viewer Plus
>   (http://download.cnet.com/MDB-Viewer-Plus/3001-10254_4-75285626.html?onid=10254)[image]
>   Read datas and insert into database however you want. Better convert the file mdb to csv and insert into database. It's easier using by PHP. Hope you have your answer

**Steps to Convert Microsoft Access Files to CSV Format**

- Open the MDB file with Microsoft access to export to a CSV format
- Click on the ‘External Data’ tab
- Select ‘Excel’ from the Export section
- “Select the destination for the data you want to export”

  - Choose an appropriate file name and location
  - Select Excel Workbook as the file format
  - Specify the appropriate export options
  - Hit the ‘OK’ button
- Open the file you just saved using Microsoft Excel
- Select File and ‘Save As’
- Click the drop-down next to ‘Save as type:’
- Change the ‘Save as type’ to ‘CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv)’
- Choose an appropriate ‘File name’
- ‘Save’ to your desktop

Hope your problem will be solved.Thanks

Comment: how to convert mdb file into CSV file using PHP code.

Comment: Please notice above, There you have your answer. (Wishing only well)