# PHP and Access query

Tags: php, ms-access, encoding, pdo, ms-access-2013

I've had a lot of trouble handling an access DB table that contains the field `quantità_gc` which is a double field and has an accent on the letter `à`. Using many examples I managed to set up a php code which at the moment no longer gives me errors, but at the same time it doesn't give me a numeric result but rather a string

```
array(1) {
["quantity_gc"]=>
string(12) "quantity_gc"
}
```

I ask you where I'm wrong and if it is possible to find a solution.
Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
<?php

$dsn = "odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/database.mdb";
$user = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Errore di connessione al database: " . $e->getMessage());
}

if (isset($_GET['variabile'])) {
    $variabile = $_GET['variabile'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 'quantità_gc' FROM magazzino WHERE id = :variabile");
    $stmt->bindParam(':variabile', $variabile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $quantità_gc = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if ($quantità_gc !== false) {
        // Applica l'encoding UTF-8 al valore del campo 'quantità_gc'
        $output = ['quantità_gc' => mb_convert_encoding($quantità_gc, "UTF-8", 'auto')];

        var_dump($output);

        // Restituisci i risultati come JSON
        //echo json_encode($output);

    } else {
        // Risultati non trovati o errore nella query
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Risultati non trovati o errore nella query']);
    }
}
?>
```

PS: I already have tried many syntax for this query,

```
SELECT '[quantità_gc]' FROM magazzino WHERE id = :variabile
```

or

```
SELECT [quantità_gc] FROM magazzino WHERE id = :variabile
```

all gives errors

Comment: *"I ask you where I'm wrong"* Don't use accented letters in field and table names. You're looking for trouble.

Comment: It's true, I can only agree with you, but the database had already been created, it contains a lot of data and a software that has been using it for years. I can't think of changing the name of several fields which unfortunately are accented.

Comment: `"SELECT [quantità_gc] FROM magazzino WHERE id = :variabile"` should work. Check the final SQL you create (`$stmt`).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I went through many tests. Here your suggest result
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC
Microsoft Access] Parametri insufficienti. Previsto 2. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260) in

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM` give the same error? Error sounds like parameters dont match placeholders. Error message also should be in the question

Comment: there are many fields in this database, and in no case do they return an error except when using the field that has the accented letter

Comment: Try encoding the query in windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @Olivier could you give me an example? I see that the encoding change has other parameters.

Comment: `$query = mb_convert_encoding($query, 'windows-1252', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks, but I think that it isn't risolutive. I'm thinking about to change the fields name in DB. (I'm crying)

Comment: You could also try the ADODB approach described at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341697/12763954).

Comment: In the Access database, create a query based on the table (just `SELECT [quantità_gc] AS YourField FROM magazzino`), and use this query in your PHP code.

Comment: @Applecore ok if I understood correctly, I should save the query in the db and use it as a ready-made external query, but I don't know how to call it from the php file, which in this case must be modified

Comment: Not a PHP guy, but shouldn't replacing `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 'quantità_gc' FROM magazzino WHERE id = :variabile");` with `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT YourField FROM YourQuery WHERE id = :variabile");` work?